# How can I link iOS notifications to aibo ERS_1000 using python?

Tags: python, ios, notifications, sony

I am currently trying to program Sony's aibo robot dog (ERS_1000 model). I would like to have the aibo bark when a notification is received on my phone. My problem is I have little experience with Python, and I am not sure how I would link my phone's notifications to my python code to be able to communicate with the aibo. If anyone has any resources I could use or suggestions on how I could implement this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You will need some device that can implement ANCS using Bluetooth to receive notifications from your phone and then send whatever is required to the dog

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. I will look into that